# Ubuntu fresh install always starts in guest session

Tags: 14.04, sudo, lightdm, gksudo

I scratch my head enough before posting this question. All fresh installation of ubuntu always resulting in getting only guest account by default. I am not able to see any option to login into my admin account. I tried with 14.04 and all higher version.

There are many posts and solution suggesting to disable guest account from lightdm but all of them using sudo command which works in admin mode only. How can I enable my admin account from guest account?

Answer (score 0):

Trying again and again, I found out that downloading updates during installation may be one of the reason. I didn't connect wifi during installation and OS (Ubuntu 14.04) properly installed. Now I am able to get the admin login option along with guest login.